# Jquery sortable plugin for unordered list multi dimension

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

This is my list multi dimensiosn :

```
     <div id="tree">
    <ul>
    <li id="205">205
         <ul>
            <li id="206">206
                      <ul>
                        <li id="208">208</li>
                        <li id="209">209</li>
                        <li id="211">211
                             <ul><li id="212">212</li>
                                 <li id="213">213</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
             </li>

    <li id="207">207
                      <ul>
                         <li id="210">210</li>
                      </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When using Jquery plugin sortable , i can only drag and drop  elements which they are in the same 'ul' tag , for exemple , if i drag the "212" tag and i dropped it after "213" tag , the plugin works fine , but if i drag "212" tag and i drop it after "206" , it did'nt work .

here is my function :

```
 $("#tree ul").sortable({ 

         opacity: 0.6, 
         cursor: 'move',
         containment : '#tree',
         grid : [10, 10]


         });
```

thinks for help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `connectWith: .someClass` feature in jQueryUI. Its in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists). Here is your **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UQrRk/)** updated.

Comment: Anytime. Glad to be of help