# Jquery sortable can't append list to another when dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have another problem with Jquery sortable plugin ,
here is my last question asked yesterday :

[Jquery sortable plugin for unordered list multi dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315391/jquery-sortable-plugin-for-unordered-list-multi-dimension).

for completing my mission , when i drop an element of my list , it's appended successfully to a list in a condition that this list  have children , and if i drop element in a list not having children , it don't work and my element return to his position . it's normal because my revert is fixed on true .

to be more explicit , when i drag '212' tag and drop it into '206' tag , it work fine (because '206' tag have already children) ,
but if i do the reverse so i drag the '206' tag (it move with its chidren) and i try to drop it into '212' tag , it did'nt work (because 212 don't have children).

i want that i can drag and drop element and in the case mentionned above for exemple '206' tag will be a child of '212' tag.

i hope that you understand me ,

thinks for help.

EDIT:

Like the receive function of sortable , which have same effect as drop in draggable function, is there a function in sortable which trigger an event when mouse enter in the tag which don't have children ?

Edit :

After a hard brainstorming :p , my idea is that i use start and stop event from sortable plugin ,

with start i'll append an ul li into tags which don't have children when the mouse is enter (event mouseenter Jquery),and i'll remove the append tags when mouse is leaving (event mouseleave Jquery)
and with stop i'll remove all event .

the result is here 
www.jsfiddle.net/UQrRk/6/
it's not working ,

any suggestion ? thinks

Comment: If you move tag 206 into tag 212, then which node would replace current tag 206's position?

Comment: with sortable plugin , it remove the 206 tag and sort the new list so it's no need to replace it ,in my case , i can drag the 206 tag and drop it into 207 tag(which have already children) but if i want to drop it into 210 tag(which don't have children ) it did'nt work and 206 tag return automatically to it's position .

Comment: here is my exemple updated http://jsfiddle.net/UQrRk/5/

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong, your end was different because you have children inside a node. tag 206 move to 212 is impossible since no way to know which children or its siblings would be replace it. You has ability to switch between same level node. http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/. If you want more, there are more problems about hierachy of nodes what you should brainstorming.

Comment: My idea is that i add an event 'dragenter' to each tag that don't have children ,so if dragged tag enter into zone of the tag which don't have children , this one will append automatically element dragged , but it din'nt work , i do brainstorming but it did'nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this problem , and i decide to explain the solution here so every body who 'll have the same problem can found the solution ,

the idea is to create 2 functions , one into start event of Jquery sortable , and the other into stop event

```
 start: function(event, ui) {
           ui.item.context.firstElementChild.remove();
            $('ul #discret').each(function() {
                $(this).show();

            });
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {

            listProject();
        }
```

in $(document).ready , you must append an ul li in the li which don't have children , after you hide them with hide() Jquery.

when sort start , we show these ul and putting a sortable item in this li(which don't have children) become simple .

when stop , we list project .

thinks for your help again.